# Open url in new tab with jQuery response

Tags: jquery

I would like to redirect to an url which I get as a response after ajax success. My code is

```
<a class="download-link" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

```
$('.download-link').on('click', function (e) {
    var self = $(this);
    var url = "<?php echo $block->getDownloadUrl()?>";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        showLoader: true,
        data: {
            type: $("#type").val(),
            docName: $("#docName").val(),
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if(response){
                self.attr("href", response.url);
                window.open(response.url, '_blank'); //This is not working for me
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do the `console.log(response.url)` and post it here please.

Comment: My ajax request is working and am getting the URL as response.

Comment: For me, Redirect action should be done on the success of my click event.

Comment: Response url is nothing but the path of my file. 
http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/media/download/file.pdf